# I can't solve this error on my circular link list when I try to run the menu driver code

Tags: c++, data-structures

Im doing the menu driver code but I keep having the error :Too few arguments to function call, single argument 'd' was not specified. I know that it may seems to obvious , but it keeps giving me the error when I try to search for the total of occurrences. I f you notice I have the similar code for total count but that seems fine. So, don't know why Im having that error

```
        case 4 : cout<<"\nThe list contains "<<l.totalCount();       //return the length of the list
                 break;
             
        case 5: l.print();                                   //Print all elements
                  break;

        case 6 :searchItem(l);                 //searchItem searches for an item in the list parameter
                break;
        case 7: cout <<"Total Occurence : " << l.totalOccurence()<< endl;  //Print all   elements
                  break;
```

total occurrence and total count are declared differently though on my header file they are

```
//Get the total number of elements in the list
int totalCount();

//Get the total number of occurence of the elements in the list
int totalOccurence(T d);
```

Comment: Well, `totalOccurence` is declared to take one argument, but you attempt to call it with none.

Comment: ***If you notice I have the similar code for total count but that seems fine*** No the other function `int totalCount();` is declared to take no arguments so it is not the same. `int totalOccurence(T d);` requires a single argument of whatever T type is.